# How to set 'number of copies' to print in electronjs?

Tags: printing, electron, web-content

I tried using this code, but it didn't work.

```
mainWindow.webContents.print({ silent: true, printBackground: false, deviceName: '',collate: true, copies: 5 } || {}, (success) => {

    })
```

I want to set how many copies to print before user click the print button in electronjs app.

Comment: Im using NW.JS for this instead of electron for now.